# how to identify if a job is a job present in job-DSL in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Hi all I have a problem and I can't seem to figure it out
I want to identify all the non job-DSL jobs. How can I do that?
I already have a python file which lists all the job. out of these I need to identify non DSL jobs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to do this. One thing you can do is to go into your Jenkins home/jobs folder. There will be a folder created for each of the jobs which will all have a `config.xml` in it. This file contains all the steps the Jenkins job has.

If the job is a DSL job, then you would either have the pipeline steps written in the job itself, or referencing a jenkinsfile in a Git repo. You can search the `config.xml` file and look for

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition
```

or

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition
```

If this exists inside a tag, then it is a DSL job. If it is a non-DSL job such as a freestyle job, it will have tags such as:

```
<builders>
<hudson.tasks.Shell>
```